# Merge multiple bar plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 3 datasets like this:

```
animal  percentage 
bear       25
lion       87
tiger      14


shape     percentage
circle     17
square     67


color     percentage
red        48
blue       5
green      11
```

I would like to plot them all on the same bar graph using ggplot2, with percentage on the y axis and then this for the x axis:

```
bear   lion    tiger           circle     square             red    blue   green
      animal                         shape                          color
```

I know how to make the graphs individually but I can't seem to get them on the same graph, I have tried facet_wrap and I can't get it to work. I also tried cbind to get it all in one dataset but since they are different lengths it also didn't work. Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your data isn't homogenous. You could reshape it to all have the same column structure, after which you can combine the data and plot it.

```r
library(ggplot2)


dat1 <- data.frame(animal = c("bear", "lion", "tiger"),
                   percentage = c(25, 87, 14))
dat2 <- data.frame(shape = c("circle", "square"),
                   percentage = c(17, 67))
dat3 <- data.frame(color = c("red", "blue", "green"),
                   percentage = c(48, 5, 11))

# Combining all the data
all <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
all <- lapply(all, function(dat) {
  dat$type <- colnames(dat)[1]
  colnames(dat)[1] <- "variable"
  dat
})
all <- do.call(rbind, all)

ggplot(all, aes(variable, percentage)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ type, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You can further match the OP's desired output by setting `facet_grid(switch = 'both')` and `theme(strip.placement = 'outside', strip.background = element_blank())`

Comment: Instead of using `do.call(rbind, ...)` you can opt for `data.table::rbindlist(...)` which tends to be much faster

Comment: @jdobres, yes that would be `strip.position = "bottom"` for `facet_wrap()` but indeed that can help. @Wietse de Vries, yes I love that function but I generally assume people (myself included) try to limit the number of packages needed to run a chunk of code.

Comment: @teunbrand I'll take any opportunity to have people install `data.table` haha, the amount of times people with sizable datasets ask for `dplyr` solutions is staggering

Comment: Indeed! There {dtplyr} if you prefer the tidyverse syntax, but data.table is nicely performant